# Alphabet Riddle - Needs improvement

Tags: riddle

This riddle started with the first line and grew from there. I can see that some of the lines need improvement. I'm curious to learn:

1. How long it takes to find the complete answer
2. What lines can be improved and how?

> My first is first and second curved. The third is fourth and fourth is third.
>   My first is all; second seventh. All together holy night.
>   First half sickness; second fun. Winter sports, to make a pun.
>   First half foolish; second hood. All together silly noob.
>   One name singer spitting candy hailing from a state so handy.
>   UFOs say au revoir to metasyntactic warrior.
>   Angel thanks for burial. Charity can ease the soul.
>   Screeching owl and his friend: swollen dangerous marine.
>   Female torture closes tight. Symbol of medieval might.
>   Classic quintet broken up. Favorite son gets hate or love.
>   Acronym appearance but came from Peter's former drums
>   Sometimes vowel; all the same. Distortion of a teacher's name.
>   Quite the mix within the troupe. Diacritic misspelled group.
>   Moonlit genies oft appear. Sun is down; desires clear.
>   Above beyond a murder spree. Members change so frequently.
>   Red as bricks with rosy hue. Named for those with color blue.
>   Ruler of the whole country. Father was a poison king.
>   Anger suggested, quite extreme. Robots? No, bureaucracy.
>   Crushing squashes makes a mess. Joke name stuck despite protests.
>   Five allure but evil not. Classic group has never stopped.
>   Name so short; it's not a lot. Named for spy plane? Maybe not.
>   Try to stop taxi Sienna. Yelling to stop and assist ya.
>   Reaching far and wide endemic. Creating world fear pandemic.
>   I heard you like to puzzle so, here's a puzzle in a puzzle, yo.
>   Particles from England rock. Temporary name got stuck.
>   Double letter up above but at the end - sometimes - of stove.

Comment: Bailey M, where are you?

Comment: Engineer Toast, are you feeling alright? You aren't going mad or anything by chance are you?

Comment: @MarkN I̮̳̪̯̬͈̙̫'̼̰̞̦̹̘̪̀m̬̟͕͇̞̕ ̸̧̨̟̹̞̱͈f̡̱̬͕̠͢ị̹͕͙̠͉n͓e̦̼͞,̘̤̯̙̬̲͜ ̡̠͙͉̕t͕ḫ̩a̸͖͎̳͘ͅn̴̗̮̭̬͈͇̟ķ̶͇̠͇͎̘̝s̵̵̷̞̘͎̦̞.̡̺̪͔͙̫͢͝ ͇̯͉̟͍͕̱̖͢H҉̨̱͇̬̖̞̮̟̗͈o̞͝ͅw̶̙̣̱̲͔͈͠ ̪a̭͎̩̖͚̠̹͓͘r͇͇̲̤̕e̴̤͚̞͖̮̰̳̱͠ ̠̭̲̠̤̱̠͞͠y҉̫̦̞̭̩̩͟ͅơ̼͇̭̤͢ͅu͏̷̰̫̤,͙̱̕ ̩͉̳̘̫̩̗͟f̫̙̤͈̠͖̮̱͍e̸̢͚̹̙͉̻l҉̹̻̘͜͜ͅl̲̖͡o̡͔̲͚͈̥̲̦͇̤w̨͇̩͈̣̕ ̛҉̬͉͔̣̘̙̱̗h̨͎͈͓̬̲̩͟ù͓̩̪̗̣̮̮͓̗͜m̪̗̦̘̩̙̞ạ̺͖ń̜̬͙̣̘̼̪͘?̨̪̼̙̹̙͜

Comment: I'm not keen on the subject, but +1 for a lovely rhythmic riddle :-)

Comment: If Morgan G's solution to line 20 is correct, I think it can definitely be improved.  It's a bit of a cop-out to use "The" as the matching word.  There are better choices.

Comment: @dennsdeems I did not take that cop-out, really. See my comment below.

Comment: @Toast my faith in you is restored! ^_^

Comment: Amazing riddle, would +10 if I could.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 26 lines, and based on the title of the puzzle, it seems obvious that they each correspond to a letter of the alphabet.

When I saw the phrase "crushing squashes," I immediately thought of

> the band "Smashing Pumpkins."
>
>  Then I noticed that that line corresponded with the letter "S" in the alphabet, and it all came clear.

So the puzzle is that

> Each line corresponds to a band or musical group of some sort, one starting with each letter of the alphabet.

The list (thanks to those who helped fill it in!):

**A)** My first is first and second curved. The third is fourth and fourth is third.

> **A**C/DC.
>
>  Words describe the letters: A = first in alphabet, C = curved, D = fourth in alphabet, C = third in alphabet

**B)** My first is all; second seventh. All together holy night.

> **B**lack Sabbath.
>
>  Not sure about the "first".  The "second seventh" is a reference to the Sabbath being the seventh day of the week.  Not entirely sure about the "holy night," either.

**C)** First half sickness; second fun. Winter sports, to make a pun.

> **C**oldplay.
>
>  A cold is a sickness, play is fun.  "Cold play" is a punny way of describing winter sports.

**D)** First half foolish; second hood. All together silly noob.

> **D**aft Punk.
>
>  Daft = foolish; a hood is a punk (think Robin Hood).  A "daft punk" could be described as a silly noob.

**E)** One name singer spitting candy hailing from a state so handy.

> **E**minem.
>
>  He's a singer with a single name, which sounds like the popular candy "M&Ms".    He's from Michigan, which apparently resembles the shape of a hand. (thanks, @Hellion)

**F)** UFOs say au revoir to metasyntactic warrior.

> **F**oo Fighters.
>
>  The band name comes from an army nickname for UFOs.  Not sure about the "au revoir" or the "metasyntactic", but "warrior" is a synonym for "fighter."

**G)** Angel thanks for burial. Charity can ease the soul.

> **G**rateful Dead.
>
>  The first sentence is a literal interpretation of the band name.  The second sentence is a reference to the origin of the band's name, which came from an encyclopedia entry for "grateful dead," which read, "the soul of a dead person, or his angel, showing gratitude to someone who, as an act of charity, arranged their burial."

**H)** Screeching owl and his friend: swollen dangerous marine.

> **H**ootie and the Blowfish. (Thanks, @BaileyM)
>
>  "Screeching owl" refers to "Hootie," and the blowfish is a "swollen dangerous marine" animal.  (Although I would argue that "marine" as a noun refers to a soldier, not a fish.)

**I)** Female torture closes tight. Symbol of medieval might.

> **I**ron Maiden.
>
>  An iron maiden is a medieval torture device which is essentially an iron coffin with spikes on the inside that would be slowly tightened around the torture victim.  "Female" refers to the "maiden."

**J)** Classic quintet broken up. Favorite son gets hate or love.

> **J**ackson Five. (thanks, @corsiKa)
>
>  They were a classic quintet who broke up.  Michael Jackson is loved by some and hated by others.

**K)** Acronym appearance but came from Peter's former drums

> **K**ISS.
>
>  "KISS" looks like an acronym and is often interpreted as "Knights in Satan's Service" or something equally inane, but actually is a play on drummer Peter Criss's former band's name, "Lips."

**L)** Sometimes vowel; all the same. Distortion of a teacher's name.

> **L**ynyrd Skynyrd.
>
>  "Y" is the "sometimes vowel"; all the vowels are the same in this name.  The band is named after the band members' physical education teacher, Leonard Skinnerd.

**M)** Quite the mix within the troupe. Diacritic misspelled group.

> **M**ötley Crüe.
>
>  A "motley crew" is a group with a lot of variety.  The dots over the "o" and "u" are diacritics, which are being used incorrectly, and the word "crue" is misspelled.

**N)** Moonlit genies oft appear. Sun is down; desires clear.

> **N**ightwish.
>
>  When wishing at night, your genie would be lit by the moon.  The second sentence is another reference to wishing at night.

**O)** Above beyond a murder spree. Members change so frequently.

> **O**verkill.
>
>  "Over" = "above" or "beyond".  "Kill" = a murder spree.  This band has had an exorbitant amount of turnover in personnel.

**P)** Red as bricks with rosy hue. Named for those with color blue.

> **P**ink Floyd.
>
>  "Red as bricks" might refer to their famous song, "The Wall."  "Rosy hue" is a reference to "Pink", and the band is named after two blues musicians ("color blue"):  Pink Anderson and Floyd Council.

**Q)** Ruler of the whole country. Father was a poison king.

> **Q**ueen.
>
>  Obviously, the queen is the ruler of the whole country.  I'm not sure what the "poison king" refers to.  That title seems to refer to Mithridates VI of Pontus, but none of his children were queens of any note.

**R)** Anger suggested, quite extreme. Robots? No, bureaucracy.

> **R**age Against the Machine.
>
>  Extreme anger = Rage.  "The machine" might sound like it's referring to robots, but it is in fact referring to bureaucracy.

**S)** Crushing squashes makes a mess. Joke name stuck despite protests.

> The **S**mashing Pumpkins.
>
>  "Crushing squashes" = "smashing pumpkins", although the "smashing" is actually intended as an adjective, not a verb.  The name was originally made up as a joke, but ended up sticking.

**T)** Five allure but evil not. Classic group has never stopped.

> The **T**emptations. (thanks, @ChrisHayes)
>
>  Allure = Temptation, but not evil.  This group has been around since the 60s.

**U)** Name so short; it's not a lot. Named for spy plane? Maybe not.

> **U**2.
>
>  The band name is very short.  There is a U2 spy plane, but its name is not related to the band's name.

**V)** Try to stop taxi Sienna. Yelling to stop and assist ya.

> **V**an Halen.
>
>  A Toyota Sienna is a model of van.  If it's being used as a taxi, and you're trying to flag it down, you're "van hailin'".  (Groan!)

**W)** Reaching far and wide endemic. Creating world fear pandemic.

> **W**idespread Panic.
>
>  Pretty self-explanatory.  A widespread panic is a pandemic of fear across a wide area.

**X)** I heard you like to puzzle so, here's a puzzle in a puzzle, yo.

> **X**zibit. (thanks, @corsiKa)
>
>  This is apparently a reference to the ["yo dawg" meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg).  (thanks, @BaileyM)

**Y)** Particles from England rock. Temporary name got stuck.

> **Y**es.
>
>  Not sure about the "particles".  The group is from England, and had to pick a temporary name for themselves when they found out another act was using the same name.  They picked "Yes", and it stuck.

**Z)** Double letter up above but at the end - sometimes - of stove.

> **Z**Z Top.
>
>  The double letter is Z.  "Top" is sometimes at the end of "stove":  "stovetop".

Comment: I'm here! H is Hootie and the Blowfish.

Comment: T is a hard one.  There doesn't seem to be a lot to go on in the clue, and there are a lot of bands that start with "The."

Comment: For T, the band name is two words. The first word *is* The but the second word also starts with a T. Everything else is what I was thinking of.

Comment: I think T is The Temptations. There are five of them; *tempting* and *alluring* mean the same thing; and they've toured from the 60s through today.

Comment: For "a state so handy", many people think the lower part of Michigan [that is, not the Upper Peninsula] resembles the outline of a hand (well, a mitten anyway).

Comment: Oh, for your description of Xzibit, it's a reference to the 'yo dawg' meme: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg.

Comment: The poison king refers to Freddie Mercury who is celebrated as a king and Mercury is poisonous.

Comment: +1 for adding the explanations. This might be bad form for an OP but here are the last few bits. B: In pigments, black is a mix of all colors; the black part of the sabbath is the night time. F: By itself, "foo" is a [metasyntactic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable). H: I felt the stretch on "marine", too. Q: Freddie Mercury / Mercury Poisoning. V: My favorite; glad it was appreciated. Y: Grammatically, "yes" is considered a particle by at least [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_and_no#cite_note-6).

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet - just wanted to add on to GentlePurpleRain's list. I think that the 20th line is

> [The Five Satins.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Five_Satins) They're a doo-wop group which was founded in 1954 - classic! - that's still active, and their name could be mistaken for The Five Satans - evil.